# Stack Overflow exception (0xC00000FD) at winsock select function

Tags: c++, select, winsock, stack-overflow

I have an application which makes use of winsock.
I/O part is handled on an other thread. 
And I am using blocking select method for sockets.
But the point is that after 5-6 hours,my application gives 0xC00000FD exception, at the line of select function.

As far as I know, this exception occurs when there is recursion, or very large local variables. But neither of them is the case for me.

So do you have any idea why am I getting this exception?
Or any ideas to discover what actually causes exception?

many thanks

EDIT 2:

Dear All, I am very sorry but since reproducing the case takes long time, I just realized that this has not solved the problem.
Everything seems ok when stack overflow exception occurs at the line of select function.

I mean it is a server socket with a one client connected. So there is 2 socket in rset and 1 in wset. After selecting, I am checking all ready sockets and making required, read,write,accept. Timeout is 250 ms. Do you think can this be the problem? I don't want this function to be blocking so it is not null. But what will be the exact difference if I use {0,0}

An important hint is:

**Same code was working without any problem, when client socket wasn't sending any data.
But when I started sending some data from client to server this problem occured.**
I am sure that there is no problem with FD_SETs and FD_CLRs, I mean when client was not sending only 1(server) socket was in rset and 1(client) was in wset.

Anyway I had a look a lot of samples, but it seems that there is not a difference.

Please see local variables screenshot below(I have deleted name of executable, since it is a commercial product)
http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/1948/stackoverflow.jpg

And here is the call stack:
ntdll.dll!7c90df3a()
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    mswsock.dll!71a53c9c()
    ntdll.dll!7c90d26c()
    mswsock.dll!71a55f9f()
    mswsock.dll!71a55974()
    ws2_32.dll!71ab314f()

> xyz.exe!vm_socket_select(vm_socket * hds=0x04c1fb84, int nhd=1, int masks=7)  Line 230 + 0x1b bytes C
>       xyz.exe!ND::nd_socket::SocketThreadProc()  Line 173 + 0x12 bytes    C++
>       xyz.exe!ND::nd_socket::ThreadRoutineStarter(void * u=0x07d63f90)  Line 332  C++
>       xyz.exe!_callthreadstartex()  Line 348 + 0x6 bytes  C
>       xyz.exe!_threadstartex(void * ptd=0x011a3ce8)  Line 326 + 0x5 bytes C
>       kernel32.dll!7c80b713()

I am waiting for any advice.
Many thanks

Comment: Can you please show us the code?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried stopping your program in a debugger after some time running? Then take a look at the stack it might give you a hint.

Recursion doesn't mean one of your functions call itself endlessly, it can't be more tricky and involve several layers before it comes back where it started.

Comment: Or just look at the stack at the time of the crash in a debugger.